# ILMerge problem: start with command prompt only

Tags: ilmerge

I build 5 DLLS and my exe in C#.Net 2.0 with ILMerge to one exe file.
The problem is that now every time I start the output exe, an empty command prompt opened with the exe. Anyone knows the problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: Did you ever find and answer to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer. The output parameter is "winexe", don't "exe". Me is it solve the problem.